# How to call custom interseptor in spring portlet?

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet

I have added my own interceptor in spring portlet i.e.

```
<bean id="portletModeParameterHandlerMapping"     class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.PortletModeParameterHandlerMapping">
            <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
                <ref bean="customInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
<property name="portletModeParameterMap">
...............
.......
</property>

<bean id="customInterceptor" class="com.xyz.CustomInterceptor"></bean>
```

And I have write CustomInterceptor class

```
class CustomInterceptor  extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter implements ServletContextAware {
//@override
public boolean preHandleAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, Object handler)  {
...............
............
}
}
```

This `CustomInterceptor` should get call for every request before controller call.
But `CustomInterceptor` not getting called by spring.
Is anything goes wrong over here?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I may be late for responding to you question but you need to use below code..

```
<bean id="customInterceptor" class="com.xyz.CustomInterceptor"></bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="customInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```